# Python - close file and IOError

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm writing a prog which writes data into a file, and each hour a new file is generated, with a precise title.
When the storage is full, it either stops the application, or deletes the oldest file created in the folder.

```
fp = open (fileNamePath, 'a')
fp.write('%s' % buffer)
try:
    fp.close()
except IOError:
    # delete file or close app
```

But when it comes to the except, it just skips it, and display IOError.

Thanks !

Comment: can you please show the error ?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I think you missed  the function call `fp.close()` when pasting , also try to use context managers

Comment: An `IOError` is raised if the file can't be opened. `file.close` doesn't raise an `IOError`

Comment: Do you have the correct rights to write to that location ?  More info about context managers: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

Comment: The error is : IOError: [errno28] No space left on the device
Python version : 2.7.13
And yes, i can write on it, that's how i filled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for solution on Google, and someone suggested to use :

```
try:
    with open(filePath,'a') as fp:
        fp.write('%s' % buffer)

except IOError as exc:
    # Handling exception
```

Well I don't get why but it works that way.

Thanks all !

Comment: Probably the IOError exception is triggered in the moment of buffer-flush writing, i.e.: `fp.write('%s' % buffer)` , which is now covered by the exception handler.

In your first try, only the file closing was covered inside the `try-except` clause.

Comment: Yes, maybe, I didn't think it would be "earlier".

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand it correctly, IOError is not catching exception but it is exploding. Did you try some more generic exception ('except Exception')?

Or you can try workaround with finally instead of except part:

```
finally:
    if not f.closed:
        # handle exception here
```

Comment: And check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215714/python-proper-way-to-catch-exceptions-on-file-close , maybe you are looking for 'EnvironmentError' and not 'IOError'.

Comment: Didn't work. I thought it would be obvious it's a IOError, as it displays a "IOError" when it doesn't catch the Exception. EnvironementError doesn't work neither.