# converting input file to list

Tags: python

I have an input file text containing following entries

```
6.56
4.64
5.75
5.59
6.32
6.54
7.20
5.33
```

how can I convert this to list looking like following

```
[6.56,4.64,5.75,5.59,6.32,6.54,7.20,5.33]
```

pls help me

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925614/how-do-you-read-a-file-into-a-list-in-python. Or at least close enough so that it gives you the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in f]
```

Comment: You don't need the `strip()` - `float()` automatically does that.

Comment: with open('filename.txt') as f: numbers = map(float, f)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen -- did you try?

Comment: @Root Ye, it only gave me string `"6.56\n"` (and rest of the numbers obviously)

Comment: @Volatility Uuupsie, sorry I read your first comment wrong :D I thought you said that both `strip()` and `float()` are useless since reading from file automatically does it. My bad, should've focused harder :P

Answer (score 1):

You could directly read it from the file by readlines (assuming one value on each line) and convert it to float.

```
values = open('filename.txt', 'rb').readlines()

values = [float(value.strip()) for value in values]
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have those values in a file named `values.txt`, you could try the following:

```
values = []
with open('values.txt', 'r') as f:
    values = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ float(i) for i in open('your_file','r').read().split('\n') if i ]
```

Comment: Wouldn't that leave an open file around?

Comment: Not sure... but doesn't appear in `lsof`.