# Strip file names from files and open recursively? Saving previous strings? - PYTHON

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a question about reading in a .txt rile and taking the string from inside to be used later on in the code.

If I have a file called 'file0.txt' and it contains:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

The rest of the files either contain more string file names or are empty.

How can I save both of these strings for later use.  What I attempted to do was:

```
infile = open(file, 'r')
line = infile.readline()
line.split('\n')
```

But that returned the following:

```
['file1.txt', '']
```

I understand that readline only reads one line, but I thought that by splitting it by the return key it would also grab the next file string.

I am attempting to simulate a file tree or to show which files are connected together, but as it stands now it is only going through the first file string in each .txt file.

Currently my output is:

```
File 1 crawled.
File 3 crawled.
Dead end reached.
```

My hope was that instead of just recursivley crawling the first file it would go through the entire web, but that goes back to my issue of not giving the program the second file name in the first place.

I'm not asking for a specific answer, just a push in the right direction on how to better handle the strings from the files and be able to store both of them instead of 1.

My current code is pretty ugly, but hopefully it gets the idea across, I will just post it for reference to what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
def crawl(file):

    infile = open(file, 'r')
    line = infile.readline()
    print(line.split('\n'))

    if 'file1.txt' in line:
        print('File 1 crawled.')
        return crawl('file1.txt')

    if 'file2.txt' in line:
        print('File 2 crawled.')
        return crawl('file2.txt')

    if 'file3.txt' in line:
        print('File 3 crawled.')
        return crawl('file3.txt')

    if 'file4.txt' in line:
        print('File 4 crawled.')
        return crawl('file4.txt')

    if 'file5.txt' in line:
        print('File 5 crawled.')
        return crawl('file5.txt')

   #etc...etc...

    else:
        print('Dead end reached.')
```

Outside the function:

```
file = 'file0.txt'
crawl(file)
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925614/how-do-you-read-a-file-into-a-list-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Using `read()` or `readlines()` will help. e.g.

```
infile = open(file, 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
print list(lines)
```

gives

```
['file1.txt\n', 'file2.txt\n']
```

or

```
infile = open(file, 'r')
lines = infile.read()
print list(lines.split('\n'))
```

gives

```
['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
```

Comment: I posted this above, but I am not getting the same output as you.  I am receiving ['file1.txt\n', 'file2.txt\n'].

Comment: that shouldn't happen with the second method. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines) for how to stop it happening with readlines

Answer (score 1):

I prepared `file0.txt` with two files in it, `file1.txt`, with one file in it, plus `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`, which contained no data.  **Note**, this won't extract values already in the list

```
def get_files(current_file, files=[]):
    # Initialize file list with previous values, or intial value
    new_files = []
    if not files:
        new_files = [current_file]
    else:
        new_files = files
    # Read files not already in list, to the list
    with open(current_file, "r") as f_in:
        for new_file in f_in.read().splitlines():
            if new_file not in new_files:
                new_files.append(new_file.strip())
    # Do we need to recurse?
    cur_file_index = new_files.index(current_file)
    if cur_file_index < len(new_files) - 1:
        next_file = new_files[cur_file_index + 1]
        # Recurse
        get_files(next_file, new_files)
    # We're done
    return new_files
        

initial_file = "file0.txt"
files = get_files(initial_file)
print(files)
```

```
Returns: ['file0.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
```

*file0.txt*

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

*file1.txt*

```
file3.txt
```

*file2.txt* and *file3.txt* were blank

Edits: Added `.strip()` for safety, and added the contents of the data files so this can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Readline only gets one line from the file so it has a newline at the end. What you want is `file.read()` which will give you the whole file as a single string. Split that using newline and you should have what you need. Also remember that you need to save the list of lines as a new variable i.e. assign to your `line.split('\n')` action. You could also just use readlines which will get a list of lines from the file.

Answer (score 0):

change `readline` to `readlines`. and no need to split(`\n`), its already a list.

[here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is a tutorial you should read

Comment: Thanks for the response, after I changed it, it is coming out as ['file1.txt\n', 'file2.txt\n'].

Comment: you can use `strip()` to remove the `\n` from each line. Ignoring the empty lines is fairly easy as well.

Comment: I didn't think you could strip from a list?

Comment: `new_list = [strip(x) for x in old_list]`. and read the tutorial you should.