# BeautifulSoup - TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I made a web crawler using python and everything runs fine until it gets to this section of the code:

```
    # Use BeautifulSoup modules to format web page as text that can
    # be parsed and indexed
    #
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
    tok = "".join(soup.findAll("p", text=re.compile(".")))
    # pass the text extracted from the web page to the parsetoken routine for indexing
    parsetoken(db, tok)
    documents += 1
```

The error I get is `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance`, Tag found around the tok line in the code.
I think my syntax could be the issue but I am not sure. How can I fix this?

Comment: what you are passing to `''.join` is not an iterable of strings, which it must be. `soup.findall` returns a sequence of some type of custom objects I can only assume

Comment: You probably need `tok = "".join([x.text for x in soup.findAll("p", text=re.compile(".")))`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

- First, I'm not sure where you're getting `response` from, but that should be a string of actual HTML.  Make sure you're not just capturing a "response" code from scraping a site that tells you whether it was successful.
- More importantly though, when you do the "findAll", note that this returns a list of BeautifulSoup objects, **not** a list of strings.  So the "`join`" command doesn't know what to do with these.  It looks at the first object in the list, sees that it's not a string, and this is why it errors out with a complaint that it "`expected str instance`".  The good news is you can use `.text` to extract the actual text from a given `<p>` element.
- Though even if you do use `.text` to extract the actual text from every `<p>` object, your `join()` may still fail if your list is a mix of `unicode` and `str` formats.  So you may have to do some encoding tricks to get everything as the same type before you join.

Here's an example I did using this very page:

```
>>> import bs4, re
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925614/how-do-you-read-a-file-into-a-list-in-python"
>>> html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> L = soup.findAll("p", text=re.compile("."))
>>> M = [t.text.encode('utf-8') for t in L]
>>> print(" ".join(M))
```

This prints the combined text of everything found in a "P" tag.

**EDIT**: This example was on Python 2.7.x.  For 3.x, drop the ".encode('utf-8')".

Comment: This is Python 3, no need for `text.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: This will *not* work on Python 3, `.encode` returns `bytes` objects, and you are trying to join using a `str` object, i.e. `" ".join`, this will throw a type error. You could do `b" ".join(...)`, but then, why would you *want* a bytes object in Python 3? Look, if Python 2 and 3 could easily be written to handle the issue of unicode strings vs bytes strings, then there would have *been no Python 2 and 3*. But otherwise, this is correct.

Comment: OK, I've updated it.  Now go back to "pulling out your hair", Juanpa.